# Decoding delimited frames from byte arrays

Tags: sockets, .net-core

I have frames that are delimited by bytes to start and stop the frame (they do not appear in the stream).

I read a chunk from disk or network socket, i then need to pass to a deserializer but only after I have de-framed the packet first.

Frames may span multiple chunks that have been read, note how frame 3 is split across `array 1` and `array 2`.

Rather than reinvent the wheel for this common problem, do any github or similar projects exist?

I am investigating `ReadOnlySequenceSegment<T>` from https://www.codemag.com/article/1807051/Introducing-.NET-Core-2.1-Flagship-Types-Span-T-and-Memory-T and will post updates as I work out the requirements.

[image: frames]

**Update**

Further to Stephen Cleary link (thank you!!) to https://github.com/davidfowl/TcpEcho/blob/master/src/Server/Program.cs I have the below.

My data is json, so unlike the original question the delimiter tokens *will* appear in the stream. Therefore I have to count the array delimitator and only declare a frame when i have found the outermost `[` and `]` characters.

The below code works, and less manual copies done (not sure if still done behind the scenes - code is quite neater using David Fowl approach).

However I am casting to array instead of using `buffer.PositionOf((byte)'[')` since I was unable to see how I could call the `PositionOf` with an offset applied (i.e. scan deeper into the frame past previously found delimiter tokens).

Am i using/butchering the library in a brute force way, or is the below good to go with the array cast?

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        using var stream = File.Open(args[0], FileMode.Open);
        var reader = PipeReader.Create(stream);

        while (true)
        {
            ReadResult result = await reader.ReadAsync();
            ReadOnlySequence<byte> buffer = result.Buffer;

            while (TryDeframe(ref buffer, out ReadOnlySequence<byte> line))
            {
                // Process the line.
                var str = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(line.ToArray());
                Console.WriteLine(str);
            }

            // Tell the PipeReader how much of the buffer has been consumed.
            reader.AdvanceTo(buffer.Start, buffer.End);

            // Stop reading if there's no more data coming.
            if (result.IsCompleted)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        // Mark the PipeReader as complete.
        await reader.CompleteAsync();     
    }

    private static bool TryDeframe(ref ReadOnlySequence<byte> buffer, out ReadOnlySequence<byte> frame)
    {
        int frameCount = 0;
        int start = -1;
        int end = -1;

        var bytes = buffer.ToArray();

        for (var i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
        {
            var b = bytes[i];

            if (b == (byte)'[')
            {
                if (start == -1)
                    start = i;

                frameCount++;
            }
            else if (b == (byte)']')
            {
                frameCount--;

                if (frameCount == 0)
                {
                    end = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (start == -1 || end == -1) // no frame found
        {
            frame = default;
            return false; 
        }

        frame = buffer.Slice(start, end+1);
        buffer = buffer.Slice(frame.Length);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do any github or similar projects exist?

David Fowler has an [echo server](https://github.com/davidfowl/TcpEcho/blob/master/src/Server/Program.cs) that uses Pipelines to implement delimited frames.

Comment: Thank you Stephen, updated my question - this solves it, just a query on token searching if you have any advise on using `PositionOf` and my replacement of `ToArray()` given my nested token searching, it would be much appreciated.